# What's the best practis to hide primary key database in url?

Tags: web, key, hidden

Actually, i have this url `http://mydomain.fr/user/1` in my web application. I think it is not very safe

I would hide the id which is auto_increment.

To not be able to do that:

```
http://mydomain.fr/user/1
http://mydomain.fr/user/2
http://mydomain.fr/user/3
http://mydomain.fr/user/4
http://mydomain.fr/user/[...]
```

I do not know which technique to use...

- Hash MD5 stored beside primary key
- UUID / GUID

I use MySQL.

Comment: Just to understand more in what scenario u feel it is not safe? GUID be ok to use in this case but not sure if it adds any benefit. 1 of the objective of Url based routing is to make user aware  where he is navigating just by reading the url only. Any use of hash or GUID in the url will make it unreadable

Answer (score 0):

You should restrict access to URLs based on authentication.  Just making it 'hard to guess' an ID will *not* prevent someone from accessing another user's page or, e.g., deleting an unexpected user.  Basically, anyone will be able to access any URL unless you provide some access control.

Answer (score 0):

I think generate a random unique string for a user is the best way.
simply use sha1 hash should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

OP may be concerned with divulging the primary keys because it could leak information into how many of a certain resource exists.

For example, if he is building a web app and someone creates an account and sees a url of domain.fr/user/23 they will know they have created an account on an application with low adoption.

My suggestion would be to either use a GUID value as suggested above or a username that is constrained to be unique.

If you use a GUID, it will look ugly, but make sure to not just use the beginning part as you could greatly increase the chance of collision since the first 60 bits are based on the timestamp.

If you use a unique username, your url would instead look like domain.fr/user/username

I know this is easily done on RoR.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way properly to hide it, you can generate unique ID with a long random hashed string, it's harder to guest. Basically that won't prevent someone to access other's ID.